# Is it possible to load balance an FTP server?

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, vps, load-balancing

I'm running Centos 5.3 on a small VPS rented from linode. We have a partner who needs to FTP us about 8 GB of data a day, and although we can make it fit on one slice, I'd prefer to have a strategy that scales a little better.

Is there a way to load balance FTP traffic?

Comment: Do you mean load balance as in, multiple connections should go to multiple machines, or do you just want to distribute the data to different servers? Or both?

Also, are you set on FTP as a protocol? There are better protocols such as RSYNC that will do differential transfers, reducing your bandwidth and transactional load.

Comment: The files are coming from a .NET server. I'm not set on FTP, but our partner likes it so if we can use it, I'd prefer it. It's mostly from a transfer/bandwidth perspective --- so if we can spread the bandwidth cost across multiple servers, it would be better

Comment: But *why* would it be better?  Are you trying to make it go faster, or save money (somehow) or what?

Comment: VPS instances usually have a bandwidth limit. Renting extra bandwidth is actually more expensive than commissioning another instance. I would prefer to turn on several instances and spread the bandwidth across them for cost reasons. Also, assuming we eventually hit our limit in the actual throughput of the devices (I've measured only about 300k/s on a wifi network), then it could also be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - [LVS](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/) will quite happily load balance FTP.